# How to check if two arrays made from different structs have the same value?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I've got two arrays made from different structs and both of them have the same information in different positions of the array.

I've tried making a double for-in loop with an if statement to check that they're the same value, but the way that I do it in other languages like PHP is not working.

Please help me, here's what I've got so far:

**Singleton One File**

```
struct oneStruct {
    var oneTitle: String
    var onePic: UIImage?
    var oneCategory: String
}

class OneSingleton {
    static let sharedInstance = OneSingleton()
    private init() {}
    var oneArray: [OneStruct] = [//you get the gist, this is full of array stuff]
}
```

**Singleton Two File**

```
struct TwoStruct {
    var twoName: String
    var twoPic: UIImage?
    var twoSubject: String
    var twoStuff1: String
    // etc. I can't get into much more here, sorry.
}

class TwoSingleton {
    static let sharedInstance = TwoSingleton()
    private init() {}
    var twoArray: [TwoStruct] = [//you get the gist, this is full of array stuff as well]
}
```

**View Controller**

```
//the singleton stuff is needed

var oneArray = [OneSingleton.sharedInstance.oneArray]
var twoArray = [TwoSingleton.sharedInstance.twoArray]
var filterArray: [TwoStruct] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for two in twoArray {
        for one in oneArray {
            if two == one {
                filterArray.append(contentsOf: two)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's giving me a compile error

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[TwoStruct]' and '[OneStruct]'

I hope this all makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the declarations of `OneStruct` and `TwoStruct` into your question. Also, I assume the type of `oneArray` is `[OneStruct]` where `twoArray` is `[TwoStruct]`?

Comment: Ok, give me a minute to edit :D That's right, oneArray is OneStruct, twoArray is TwoStruct.

Comment: I've made those changes, the two elements I want to check that are the same are the oneCategory and twoSubject.

Comment: @TMI make them one struct and implement  Eqauatble for compasrion parameters , i will edit

Comment: No, they have to be different. They're not related at all except for the category and the subject.

Comment: see answer , change attributes name as you want in struct and comparison

Comment: "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[TwoStruct]' and '[OneStruct]'" Makes perfect sense. What would it mean to ask whether a OneStruct instance "equals" a TwoStruct instance? They have different properties, so what would make them "the same" as each other. You have not told the compiler, and you have not told _us_. What's your intention here? What does "have the same information" mean, _exactly_?

Comment: @TMI consider giving some feedback on the provided answers.

Answer (score -1):

To compare implement `Equatable` for both and change the lhs or rhs to the other object

```
struct OneStruct :Equatable {

    var value1: String
    var value2: UIImage? /// image comparsion is not an easy way you may add id of image
    var value3: String

   // also you can omit any static method part from any class 

    static func ==(lhs: TwoStruct, rhs: OneStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value1 == rhs.value1 && lhs.value3 == rhs.value3
    }

}

struct TwoStruct :Equatable {

    var value1: String
    var value2: UIImage? /// image comparsion is not an easy way you may add id of image
    var value3: String

    // also you can omit any static method part from any class 

    static func ==(lhs: OneStruct, rhs: TwoStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value1 == rhs.value1 && lhs.value3 == rhs.value3
    }
 }
```

//

```
let s1 = OneStruct(value1: "", value2: UIImage.init(named: ""), value3: "")
let s2 = TwoStruct(value1: "", value2: UIImage.init(named: ""), value3: "")

if s1 == s2 {


}
```

Comment: This will just allow two instances of e.g. `OneStruct` to be compared to each other, but will not help comparing an instance of `OneStruct` to `TwoStruct`.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly, but what if they're not similar in structure? There's only 1 thing that's similar in both of them.

Comment: Note that the `Equatable` conformance here has nothing to do with the `==` comparison operator between the two different types: conforming to `Equatable` (in this case) just provides [synthesizing `Equatable` conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md) as all members of `OneStruct` and `TwoStruct` happens to be `Equatable` themselves. If you add a member to e.g. `OneStruct` that is not `Equatable` (e.g. a dummy one), you'll notice that you'll get a compilation error.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have, for each of your types `OneStruct` and `TwoStruct`, one respective property that you would like to use for comparison; `category` and `subject`, respectively. So to start out, lets blueprint two protocols for these two properties:

```
protocol Categorizable {
    var category: String { get }
}

protocol Subjectable {
    var subject: String { get }
}
```

For the purpose of this example, minimal examples of `OneStruct` and `TwoStruct` would then conform to `Categorizable` and `Subjectable`, respectively:

```
struct OneStruct: Categorizable {
    var category: String
    init(_ category: String) { self.category = category }
}

struct TwoStruct: Subjectable {
    var subject: String
    init(_ subject: String) { self.subject = subject }
}
```

Now, we don't really want to talk about *equality* when comparing two different types, rather equivalent classes or bi-predicates over which instances of these two types can be compared. So let's define e.g. a bi-predicate that can be used to compare two instances conforming to `Categorizable` and `Subjectable`, respectively:

```
struct BiPredicate<T: Categorizable, U: Subjectable> {
    static func compare(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> Bool {
        return lhs.category == rhs.subject
    }
    static func compare(_ lhs: U, _ rhs: T) -> Bool {
        return compare(rhs, lhs)
    }
}
```

Based on your own example code, it seems that you want two filter an array of `TwoStruct` (namely, an array of a type conforming to `Subjectable`) based on whether, for each element in the array, there exist a member in an array of `OneStruct` (namely, an array of a type conforming to `Categorizable`) for which the equivalent class or bi-predicate holds true.

```
/// Returns `lhs` argument filtered based on its BiPredicate intersection
/// with the `rhs` argument.
/// Time complexity: O(n^2)
func filterByIntersect<T: Subjectable, U: Categorizable>(_ lhs: [T], over rhs: [U]) -> [T] {
    return lhs.filter { l in rhs.contains { r in BiPredicate.compare(l, r) } }
}
```

Which we may use as:

```
let oneArray = [OneStruct("foo"), OneStruct("bar"), OneStruct("baz"), OneStruct("bax")]
let twoArray = [TwoStruct("baxx"), TwoStruct("foo"), TwoStruct("bax")]

let result = filterByIntersect(twoArray, over: oneArray)
for twoElement in result { print(twoElement.subject) } /* foo
                                                          bax */
```

---

Now, this was mostly a somewhat interesting exercise, but in the end ended up in quite a lot of boilerplate code for something that should be quite a simple task. You could always drop the generics and just go with a simple function for testing a single equivalent class over `OneStruct` and `TwoStruct`:

```
func compareCategoryWithSubject(_ lhs: OneStruct, _ rhs: TwoStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.category == rhs.subject
}

/// Returns `lhs` argument filtered based on intersection over comparing 
/// the `subject` properties of the elements of `lhs` with the `category`
/// properties of the elements of `rhs`.
/// Time complexity: O(n^2)
func filterByIntersect(_ lhs: [TwoStruct], over rhs: [OneStruct]) -> [TwoStruct] {
    return lhs.filter { l in rhs.contains { r in
        compareCategoryWithSubject(r, l) } }
}
```

Or, for a possibly even simple and also asymptotically more performant approach, placing all the logic into the `filterByIntersect(...)` function:

```
/// Returns `lhs` argument filtered based on intersection over comparing
/// the `subject` properties of the elements of `lhs` with the `category`
/// properties of the elements of `rhs`.
/// Time complexity: O(n) [contains(_:) is O(1) for Set)
func filterByIntersect(_ lhs: [TwoStruct], over rhs: [OneStruct]) -> [TwoStruct] {
    let rhsCategories = Set(rhs.map { $0.category })
    return lhs.filter { l in rhsCategories.contains(l.subject) }
}
```

Both the above yielding the same result as above:

```
let oneArray = [OneStruct("foo"), OneStruct("bar"), OneStruct("baz"), OneStruct("bax")]
let twoArray = [TwoStruct("baxx"), TwoStruct("foo"), TwoStruct("bax")]

let result = filterByIntersect(twoArray, over: oneArray)
for twoElement in result { print(twoElement.subject) } /* foo
                                                          bax */
```

Comment: I thought of protocol also , but find changing the lhs or rhs is much easier